# ¿Cómo evitar que se elimine los datos de mi textArea al recargar la pagina?

Tags: html, textarea

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto HTML, donde tengo un `textarea` que contiene la dirección del correo del usuario, quisiera saber si hay una manera de que al recargar la página no se elimine lo que tengo escrito en él.

Este es mi textarea:

```html
<div class="form-group col-xl-12">
  <textarea id="tiendaEmail" rows="1" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Email"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Para evitar que no elimine al recargar deberías almacenar los valores en algún lugar, como localstorage.

Para que tu input tiendaEmail guarde los cambios, debes almacenarlo en el localstorage con una key y recuperarlo al cargar la página.

```javascript
    //registro una funcion para registrar el event listener.
    window.onload = () => {

      //selecciono el input.
      const tiendaEmail = document.getElementById('tiendaEmail');
      
      //obtenemos el valor del local storage con la funcion getItem, si no existe lo asignamos vacio.
      tiendaEmail.value = window.localStorage.getItem('tiendaemailkey') || "";
      
      //registramos un listener al evento focustout para guardar el valor.
      tiendaEmail.addEventListener('focusout', (event) => {
      //almacenas el valor del input en el local storage.
      window.localStorage.setItem('tiendaemailkey', tiendaEmail.value);
      });

    }
```

Puedes leer sobre el mismo en:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage